# Salesforce Lightning Component - Add to a Page, not an app

Tags: salesforce1-app, page-layout, lightning-aura-components

Whilst trying out the Salesforce lightning developer guide, I have noticed that it's not saying anything about adding a lightning component to a page.

At Dreamforce, I followed a couple of sessions about the lightning components. During these sessions, demo's were provided in which particular components where replacing, for instance a field on a page layout. Unfortunately, I was unable to follow a workshop for the lightning builder.

How do you replace a field on a page layout with a lightning component? Or does this needs to be done by the lightning builder for which we need to request access to?

Cheers,
Robin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that you might be thinking about Lightning Extensions which are in Pilot.  From the [Lightning FAQ](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Lightning_FAQ):

> Q: What are Lightning Extensions?
>   A: They’re a mechanism for using custom-built components to replace existing components in the Salesforce1 Mobile App. This functionality is currently in Pilot.

AND

> Q: What Components of Salesforce1 are the next extension points coming up besides Tabs and Fields?
>   A: We’re not commenting publicly about our release plan.

[This answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/54120/154) refers to the pilot and how you can try to get involved.  Note that the App Builder is also in pilot.

> ...the UI Plugins are part of an upcoming set of product features currently referred to as Lightning Extensions. These are in pilot for Winter '15, and will likely remain so for at least one more release. If you're interested in joining the pilot, please contact your SE, TSE, etc. and ask that they nominate you. Stay tuned for more information on this great companion to Lightning Components.

Also, many DF14 presenters have posted their presentations to the session's chatter feed.  You can log in and download it.  If it isn't there you can chatter at the presenter and ask for it.  Soon, the technical sessions will be [available on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/user/dreamforce).