# Copy field from Activity Object to Contact Object

Tags: custom-field

I wonder if there is a declarative way of doing this.
When my Activity is closed, I want to copy a custom field of the Activity Object onto a custom field on my Contacts object. Is there a way to do that declaratively?
Otherwise, what's the best way of doing this?
Tia.

Comment: Is your Activity an Event or a Task ?

Comment: The activity is a task

Answer (score 1):

Basically there are 2 approaches: standard workflows and triggers.

At Workflows to my knowledge the field updates are only available for the same object and objects related as Master in a Master-Detail relationship, so it may not work, since the WhoId is a polymorphic Lookup(Contact,Lead).

With a trigger it will work for sure.

I third option could be to try Visual Workflows, but this I have not verified yet:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/

According to this post [What is the difference between Aura and Lightning frameworks?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/53232/what-is-the-difference-between-aura-and-lightning-frameworks/53301#53301) the Lightning Process Builder is a kind of rebrand of Visual Workflows. If my time allows, I'll have a look into both and give feedback here.

Comment: Yes, Workflows are only for the same object. I am just a bit confused how to do the trigger. Any pointers?

Comment: yes, use the search function here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=first+trigger and read on :-)

Answer (score 0):

There does exist, in limited cases, the possibility to copy values across relationships with workflow field update...particularly master-detail relationships and certain standard relationships.

The problem with Activity - Contact (whether task or event) is that the field used to connect the Activity is called WhoId. And WhoId can *either* be a Lead or a Contact. We call this polymorphic...in orther words the related "who" on the other end can be one of many different types of objects.

This is often an obstacle in declarative customization. There has been some progress in being able to write formulas working with polymorphic keys a little over a year ago, which was [the subject of a blog](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/06/cross-object-owner-fields-a-powerful-new-formula-option.html) on the salesforce developers site. But unfortunately, cross-object field updates are different from writing formulas.

I'm afraid to do this you'd need to do something in code. Although...one thing I have seen is some interesting functionality in the new Lightning Process Builder. Once that goes GA, there might be a new alternative.