# Formula field - refer to another object

Tags: formula

I have 2 objects with some custom fields.

```
Obj1: Field1(picklist)
Obj2: Field2(Formula), Field3(Checkbox)
```

I want to say the following:

```
if field3 is checked AND Obj1.Field1 == 'Value1" THEN assign Value1 to Field2
```

I am fine with the formula, but I just cannot reference Field1 on Obj1. I tried `Obj1.Field1`, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Reading Values**

In Formula fields you can only access fields from related objects (master-detail or lookup) and only upstream, that means e. g. on opportunity you can access Account.Name but not OpportunityLineItem.UnitPrice

**Writing Values**

You can't access related objects. Formulas can not assign values to any other fields but to itself. To do so, you may look into Workflows (limited cross-object capabilities for master-detail relations) or Triggers.

**Flows / Lightning process builder**

I other option could be to try Visual Workflows, but this I have not verified yet: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/

According to this post [What is the difference between Aura and Lightning frameworks?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/53232/what-is-the-difference-between-aura-and-lightning-frameworks/53301#53301) the Lightning Process Builder is a kind of rebrand of Visual Workflows. If my time allows, I'll have a look into both and give feedback here.